# emberjs add code on the fly, after template render

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

In emberjs, you can add code to your template file:

```
{{input type="text" value=color}}
```

the template then renders.  But the question is, how can you add this dynamically after the template renders?  For example, I want to add a button, to generate new input fields (colors), and the user can continue to add new colors as needed?  How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to let user add another input for color, I am sure that you want to somehow access the value user inputs after all - e.g. in some action. Therefore, you will have to make some bindings that will store that values.

Let's say you need to store them in some kind of an array - e.g. `colors`. This array will be initially containing only one object, automatically added when user enters the route. This setup (e.g. in `setupController` hook in route) may look like this:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set("colors", []);
  controller.get("colors").pushObject({ value: "" });
}
```

And let's handle the click on the button by an action in controller:

```
actions: {
  handleClick: function() {
    this.get("colors").pushObject({ value: "" });
  }
}
```

Then, your template can look like this:

```
{{#each color in colors}}
  {{input type="text" value=color.value}}
{{/each}}
```

Using `pushObject` method make pushing binding-compliant. Every time you push anything to `colors` array, the template will automatically rerender and inject another `input` field with properly binded `value` to `color.value`. Thanks to that, in some other action (like submit) you can access all the values provided by the user and process them as you want.

Comment: Makes perfect sense seeing how you have shown it above.  Thank you!  Very clear and easy to understand!